# ANT seems to be corrupting chinese character when deploying project

Tags: xml, ant, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an XSL file which contains the following text:

```
<xsl:variable name="orderName" select="'@ORDER_NAME@'"/>
```

At the top of the XSL file the encoding is set to UTF-8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

And if I check the file properties in Eclipse, the Text file encoding is listed as:
    **Default (determined from content type: UTF-8)**

There is then an ANT filter set file:

```
<project name="filterset" basedir=".">
    <property name="conn" value="TEST"/>
    <filterset id="conn_props">
        <filter token="ORDER_NAME" value="${ORDER_NAME}"/>
    </filterset>
</project>
```

The value of **ORDER_NAME** is then defined in a .properties file

```
ORDER_NAME=电子客票
```

Here's an excerpt from the ANT deploy.xml which is run for deployment

```
<copy todir="${working.dir}/config" failonerror="false" overwrite="true" encoding="UTF-8">
    <fileset dir="${supplier.dir}">
        <include name="Supplier/**/*.xsl"/>
        <include name="Supplier/**/*.xml"/>
    </fileset>
    <filterset refid="conn_props"/>
</copy>
```

This should copy the XSL file from the **Supplier** directory to the **config** directory and replacing the **ORDER_NAME** token.
However after deploying the project and opening the file the text is corrupted to:

```
<xsl:variable name="orderName" select="'çµå­å®¢ç¥'"/>
```

I'm running this on Windows 7 64-bit, on Eclipse Juno 32 bit with ANT 1.7.1 (Ant version cannot be upgraded). I have seen similar questions, but not any with satisfactory answers (or any that seem to apply to this particular scenario).
Thanks.

Comment: What is the orginal encoding also UTF-8?

Comment: @rekire - yes the xsl file containing the Chinese characters is shown by Eclipse as having UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I am unable to duplicate with ant 1.8.4 it might be an environment problem.

Comment: This appears to duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688089/ant-copy-task-corrupts-utf-8-symbols

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself, but it is possible others were not able to duplicate my issue as a result of me leaving information out of my original question for simplification (I've since edited the question for clarity).

The problem was the file type of the properties file containing:

```
ORDER_NAME=电子客票
```

was **UTF-8** and it needs to be **ISO-8859-1**, as this is what is expected by ANT, see:
[Apache Ant Property](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html)

So converting the file to be ISO-8859-1 and redefining ORDER_NAME:

```
ORDER_NAME=\u7535\u5B50\u5BA2\u7968
```

Results in the XSL file containing:

```
<xsl:variable name="orderName" select="'电子客票'"/>
```

As expected.